# SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2, osx-lion, reachability

I am getting the following error in the file Reachability.h. I have the required framework. What else do I need to do? This is an app made in Xcode3 and I am trying to import in Xcode4.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support. Whats the correct syntax for these `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20"
`

Comment: I see the SystemConfiguration framework is listed in the project group; but can you check that it is linked (Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries)?

Comment: Yes I dragged it from there only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing Xcode removed the error.

Comment: I had the identical error. Tried everything. Reinstalling Xcode did indeed solve it. Thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: In case anyone having this issue sees this answer and is wondering if it's still valid, I had this issue in Xcode 6 Beta 2 and reinstalling fixes it.