# Xcode 7 - SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h file not found

Tags: swift2, xcode7, watchos-2

I know that there is another thread with the same topic ([SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685101/systemconfiguration-systemconfiguration-h-file-not-found)) but I haven't enough reputation to commit these thread. And because Xcode 3 was used I decide to create a new thread.

I create an Apple Watch project on Xcode 6 and now I migrate it to Xcode 7, Swift 2 and WatchOS 2.

I use the SDK from apiOmat. And in this SDK they use `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>`.

I looked for a solution in the internet and try to create a precompiled header but it doesn't work for me. The header isn't found.

I also try to reinstall Xcode 7, but this also doesn't work.

Here you can see my precompiled header:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

#endif
```

I hope really that you can help me to fix this problem.

P.S.: I'm using Swift 2 and a bridging header.

Comment: did you find a solution for this already?

Comment: It seems so. Please look at my answer.

Comment: I see, so you're using AFNetwork with Cocoapods?

Comment: I haven't solve the problem at all. But I really confident that this is my problem.